# how to update composer in zend framework 2 on wamp so that i can use zendserivice/twitter library

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php

I am getting error in updating composer. i have tried this command in my command prompt."service" is my project name.

```
C:\wamp\www\service>composer update
Composer could not find the config file: C:\Program Files (x86)\ComposerSetup
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the
https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section"
```

composer.json  is already there in my "service" project. i have also installed composer.exe from "https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows"